# Rails view not rendering HTML code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and try to build a little project to get familiar with the framework. I'm currently trying to build a very simple view that indicates how many stars the average rating gave (kind of like the Amazon 5-Star rating system). This one problem I can not figure out myself. I built a "stars_view" but the rails code won't render any html. It's probably some beginner's mistake but I did not find it for days.

This is how I render the partial view:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <h2><%= @document.title %></h2>
  <%= render :partial=>'application/stars_view', :locals => {:number_of_stars => @document.average_rating_number_of_stars} %>
    <br/>von
    <%= @document.user.email %>
      <br/>
      <p>
        <%= @document.description %>
      </p>
</div>
```

This is the code of my partial:

```
<div id="stars_view">
  Stars
  <%=
    #this link is for test purposes but even this does not show.
    link_to 'Back', documents_path
    rounded_number_of_stars = (number_of_stars.to_int*2.0)/2.0
    max_number_of_stars = 5
    drawn_number_of_stars = 0
    while rounded_number_of_stars >= 1 do
      image_tag("stars/star_full.png", :class => "img-responsive")
      rounded_number_of_stars -= 1
      drawn_number_of_stars += 1
      #byebug stops here
      #byebug
    end
    if rounded_number_of_stars == 0.5
      image_tag("stars/star_half.png")
      drawn_number_of_stars += 1
      #and here
      #byebug
    end
    while drawn_number_of_stars < max_number_of_stars do
      image_tag("stars/star_empty.png")
      drawn_number_of_stars += 1
      #and here
      #byebug
    end
  %>
</div>
```

This is the HTML code I get in Safari:

```
<div id="stars_view">
  Stars

</div>
```

I know there are probably some bugs in the view itself. I will solve those later. For now any help making rails generate any HTML would be appreciated. The partial is saved as application/_stars_view.html.erb, all the images should be in the right place too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<%=` syntax only outputs the last thing your code returns. Not everything in it. That's why you see no output.

Everything you want to show on the screen needs to be in it's own `<%=` tag.
To run arbitrary code use `<%`.

For example:

```
<%- while rounded_number_of_stars >= 1 do %>
  <%= image_tag("stars/star_full.png", :class => "img-responsive") %>
  <%  rounded_number_of_stars -= 1
      drawn_number_of_stars += 1
   %>
<% end %>
```

Etcetera.